# How do I GroupBy one column on this DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Suppose I have a call log DataTable where each row represents a call placed with the following columns:
AccountNumber1, AccountNumber2, AccountListDate, AccountDisposition

I want to GroupBy column AccountNumber1 and want a new DataTable with the same columns + 1 additional column NumCalls which will be the count of calls for each AccountNumber1.

New DataTable after GroupBy:
AccountNumber1, AccountNumber2, AccountListDate, AccountDisposition, NumCalls

So far I have the following:

```
table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("AccountNumber1"))
    .Select(x => new { x.Key.AccountNumber1, NumCalls = x.Count() })
    .CopyToDataTable()
```

Which gives me a DataTable with just two columns AccountNumber1 and NumCalls. How do I get the other columns as I described above?? I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Your code does not compile, because that `Select` overload doesn't exist and the `CopyToDataTable` needs `IEnumerable<DataRow>` as input.

Comment: Also, if you only group by the first column, which rows you want to use to get the other columns' values?

Comment: @TimSchmelter my bad, when I was typing the example code I forgot the new anonymous type declaration in the Select()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic, you need to use a loop and initialize the new table with the new column:

```
DataTable tblResult = table.Clone();
tblResult.Columns.Add("NumCalls", typeof(int));
var query = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("AccountNumber1"));
foreach (var group in query)
{
    DataRow newRow = tblResult.Rows.Add();
    DataRow firstOfGroup = group.First();
    newRow.SetField<string>("AccountNumber1", group.Key);
    newRow.SetField<string>("AccountNumber2", firstOfGroup.Field<string>("AccountNumber2"));
    newRow.SetField<DateTime>("AccountListDate", firstOfGroup.Field<DateTime>("AccountListDate"));
    newRow.SetField<string>("AccountDisposition", firstOfGroup.Field<string>("AccountDisposition"));
    newRow.SetField<int>("NumCalls", group.Count());
}
```

This takes arbitrary values from the first row of each group which seems to be desired.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid that would be the case. Was hoping there was some way to do it in one quick swoop with Linq after the .GroupBy().

Comment: @JDSchenck: `CopyToDataTable` always creates a new table with the same schema/columns as the input table(rows). But you need another column.